# Add row in google chart AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I use [Google chart](https://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/generic/BarChart) for create chart. But I have a problem.
Now I have a chart, created like this (Example in page ofgoogle chart):

```
/* global angular */
angular.module("google-chart-sample").controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.onions = [
        {v: "Onions"},
        {v: 3},
    ];

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};


    // $routeParams.chartType == BarChart or PieChart or ColumnChart...
    $scope.chartObject.type = $routeParams.chartType;
    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
});
```

If I would like modified that chart adding a row, how can I do?

I would add "apple" so `$scope.chartObject.data` will be:

```
$scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Apple"},
            {v: 7},
        ]}
    ]};
```

Anyone can tell me how I can add "Apple" by code? I supposed that there is a method like addRow or something like this.

Comment: what is the problem of doing `$scope.chartObject.data.rows.push({c: [
            {v: "Apple"},
            {v: 7},
        ]})`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks men !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `Push()` as below.

```
var newC =  {c: [
            {v: "Apple"},
            {v: 7},
        ]};

$scope.chartObject.data.rows.push(newC);
```